# Running openai tools from vs code powershell terminal on windows

Tags: powershell, openai-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to run the openai tools from a Powershell terminal in Windows (VSCode). On attempting to run finetune it just attempts to open the file...

[image: Open file]

[image: Content]